# Not Getting Authorization Header in SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, angular, signalr, signalr-hub

How I can apply [Authorize] in SignalR Hub, Its working on my other API controllers but not working in SignalR Hub and I can send JWT token in SignalR request.
This is my C# code of SignalR Hub

```
namespace LC_ERP
{
    public class UsersHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, bool> _userStatuses = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        [UserSession]
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            // Get the user ID from the JWT token in the connection request
             var userId = GetUserIdFromToken(Context);

            // Set the user status to true (online)
            _userStatuses[userId] = true;

            // Notify all connected clients of the updated user status
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("UserStatusUpdated", userId, true);

            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        [UserSession]
        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            // Get the user ID from the JWT token in the connection request
            var userId = GetUserIdFromToken(Context);

            // Set the user status to false (offline)
            _userStatuses[userId] = false;

            // Notify all connected clients of the updated user status
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("UserStatusUpdated", userId, false);

            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }

        private string GetUserIdFromToken(HubCallerContext context)
        {
            var token = context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();
            var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwtToken = jwtHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);

            return jwtToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "id")?.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Thats my angular code where I'm adding header:

```
var token:any = jwtService.getJwtToken();

    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(`${environment.apiURL}/users`, { accessTokenFactory: () =>  token})
    .build();
    

    //console.log(jwtService.getJwtToken())
    this.hubConnection.on('UserStatusUpdated', (userId: string, isOnline: boolean) => {
      this.userStatuses[userId] = isOnline;
    });

    this.hubConnection.start();
```

In signalR, first issue is that the [Authorize] attribute is not working and second issue is that I'm getting null in this line:

```
var token = context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();
```

When I try to get the Authorization header, it returns null.

Comment: Bear in mind that SignalR abstracts away the transport details and *some transports may have no concept of headers*. You are *not* guaranteed that a particular invocation of a hub method is related to a specific HTTP request.

Comment: Then how I can make it secure?